# How to efficiently use Servicebus as communication through multiple webjobs

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

*This is more of an architectural question which is probably an edge case of being allowed on SO. If it's not allowed, please any advise on how to update my question to be allowed*

We have 7-8 Webjobs running that are supposed to process the same info in a specific order. What is the preferred way of doing this with servicebus? Is there best practice to use the servicebus for this?

At the moment I'm at something like this:
[image]

**See EDIT, this has been changed**
The packet comes in from our clients, goes through 2 jobs, and then gets sent to 3 jobs (not all of them are always necessary, they're sharing jobs. Some packets go to facebook, some to FTP, some both,.. And only after all 3 of them are done the last Job can proceed, since it's based on the info the 3 jobs give.

We could write states to the database, but we're specfically switching to servicebus to work transactional with our packets, have an easy way to recover on crashes and so on.

Also, would the best way be 4 different servicebusses or 1 bus where (if that is even possible) we requeue the same packet with a state field? For example add a statefield "Job1=OK" and Job 2 has a subscription on that field, so that it gets the packet when it's passed Job1. That would be ideal, it would also miminize the traffic to the servicebus since the packet stays on it until the end..

After some searching I found that I can forward messages, but can I forward them to the same topic too? And can I add data to them? And if I forward a message, does that count as an extra message in pricing?

**EDIT: Updated the flow to this:**

[image]

So there is no need to wait for the 3 jobs anymore. One Job just didn't need any waiting apparently, and the other 2 are merged.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a bit different.

- Why not to use different queues? For instance Step1, Step2, Step3 and so on (For sure you should do better naming). Then in web job you can create handlers

  ```
  public static void ProcessJob1([QueueTrigger("Job1")] CloudQueueMessage data, CancellationToken token){
     var message = data.AsString;
     //process event
     //Send event for next job2
  }

    public static void ProcessJob2([QueueTrigger("Job2")] CloudQueueMessage data, CancellationToken token){
     var message = data.AsString;
     //process event
     //Send event for next job3
  }

  .....
  ```
- I am using storage queue so i am sending json in service bus as soon as i recall you can ask it to deserialize
- Merge webjobs to one webjob and use scaling, this means that you will use resources properly, because some events could use more resources some less
- No need to redirect if you finish step 2 send one more event to other queue so web job will pick it up as new item.

In addition you can check [other approach](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors) and [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt595752.aspx) but it will require to rewrite you app a bit

Comment: The reason to split it out is mostly to be able to go transactional. Job 1 for example is a video processing job, job 2 is facebook sharing, job 3 is mailing that facebookshare,.. When we merge it all in one job we have to keep states in the database again to pick up again on crashes. Since we want to get away from writing continuously to the database and use the transactional idea of servicebus that's not the best approach I think. The 3 'split' jobs are merged now though.

Comment: @Lonefish its one job, but you will have different processors inside of it, so technically it will be a bit same, and yes in this case servicebus is best choise since there is functionality were you can reschedule on error, or delay.

Comment: @Lonefish so in one webjob you will have 3 static methods ProcessJob1([QueueTrigger("Job1")]), ProcessJob2([QueueTrigger("Job2")] ) in the end of processing event you will need to send next job event

Comment: Since I need 2 seperate subscriptions on 2 out of 3 messages I have my doubts on queues, as I read it this is one of the advantages of topics over queues. Or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: @Lonefish sorry its me confusing you. You should stay with topic/subscription since they have some advanced cool features. but concept is the same so in my answer by queue i mean queue or topic